# Odoo domain for Many2Many relation

Tags: odoo

Here is code:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    _name = 'car'
    parking_id = fields.Many2one('cars')

class Parking(models.Model):
    _name = 'parking'
    cars_ids = fields.One2many('cars', 'parking_id')

class Group(models.Model):
    _name = 'group'
    parking_id = fields.Many2one('parking')
    cars_ids = fields.Many2many('cars', lambda self: [('parking_id', '=', self.parking_id)])
```

What i want is to limit records of cars when i picking it in group form by parking on that cars are.
But my code does not work. What the mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your syntax is wrong for domain, change as below:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    _name = 'group'
    parking_id = fields.Many2one('parking')
    cars_ids = fields.Many2many('cars', domain=[('parking_id', '=', parking_id)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the domain in python code it will not be changed after the user
select the `parking_id` you need to update the domain every time the user 
changes the `parking_id`:

```py
    class Group(models.Model):
        _name = 'group'
        parking_id = fields.Many2one('parking')
        # it's always better to define m2m field with full properties
        # cars_ids = fields.Many2many('cars','group_cars_rel', 'group_id', 'car_id', 'List of cars' )
        cars_ids = fields.Many2many('cars')


        @api.onchange('parking_id')
        def onchange_parking(self):
            """change the domain when user change parking_id"""
            # you may need to empty the many2many field if the user change the parking
            # if not just remove this line
            self.cars_ids = [(5, 0, 0)] # remove all record from many2many

            if self.parking_id:
                return {'domain': {'cars_ids': [('parking_id', '=', self.parking_id.id)]}}
            else:
                # remove domain
                return {'domain': {'cars_ids': []}}
```